# Cleaning JSON data

Tags: angularjs, json

I am trying to clean the JSON data i have i.e. remove the N/A and null data. I am trying to use $.each to clean the data however it has no effect on the data.

```
.controller('APICtrl', function($scope, $http, $localstorage, $window, $state, $sce) {
// Search function
//var offices = [];
var n;
  $scope.query = {}
  $scope.queryBy = '$'
// gets the data from offices.json
 $http.get('js/offices.json').then(function(resp) {
    console.log('Success', resp);
    $scope.offices = $.each(resp.data.office, function(key,value){
   //console.log(value);
    if(value==""||value==null){
        delete resp.data.office[key];
    }
});
    //console.log(offices)
  }, function(err) {
    console.error('ERR', err);
    // err.status will contain the status code
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

instean jquery functions

```
$scope.offices = $.each(resp.data.office, function(key,value){
```

use standart angular functions

```
$scope.offices = angular.forEach(resp.data.office, function(key,value){
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Answer (score 0):

Do you have jQuery included? Otherwise my guess is that you're getting an error that is being silenced because it's inside of a `then`. This should work:

```
.controller('APICtrl', function($scope, $http, $localstorage, $window, $state, $sce) {
  // Search function
  //var offices = [];
  var n;
  $scope.query = {};
  $scope.queryBy = '$';
      // gets the data from offices.json
  $http.get('js/offices.json').then(function(resp) {
      console.log('Success', resp);

      var office = resp.data.office;

      angular.forEach(office, function(value, key){
        if (value == "" || value == null) {
            delete office[key];
        }
      });

      $scope.offices = office;
      //console.log(offices)
  }, function(err) {
      console.error('ERR', err);
      // err.status will contain the status code
  });
});
```

Comment: I do have jQuery included, i am using Ionic and AngularJS, i have tried this solution but it doesn't work i'm afraid it still has no effect on the data.